# Tab Traversal is not working with wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER and AutoComplete

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to get a textCtrl with AutoComplete function, `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` enabled and tab traversal to work.

Tab traversal works if I either disable the `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` switch or do no auto-complete.

Here I have a small sample code that illustrates my problem.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( -1,-1 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        Sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.panel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        inputSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.no_process_enter = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        inputSizer.Add( self.no_process_enter, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.no_autocomplete = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
        inputSizer.Add( self.no_autocomplete, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
        inputSizer.Add( self.autocomplete_and_process_enter, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        ButtonSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.ButtonSizerOK = wx.Button( self.panel, wx.ID_OK )
        ButtonSizer.AddButton( self.ButtonSizerOK )
        self.ButtonSizerCancel = wx.Button( self.panel, wx.ID_CANCEL )
        ButtonSizer.AddButton( self.ButtonSizerCancel )
        ButtonSizer.Realize();

        inputSizer.Add( ButtonSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.panel.SetSizer( inputSizer )
        self.panel.Layout()
        inputSizer.Fit( self.panel )
        Sizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( Sizer )
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.no_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.no_process_enterOnKillFocus )
        self.no_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.no_process_enterOnSetFocus )
        self.no_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown )
        
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.no_autocompleteOnKillFocus )
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.no_autocompleteOnSetFocus )
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.no_autocompleteOnTextEnter )
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown )
        
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.autocomplete_and_process_enterOnKillFocus )
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.autocomplete_and_process_enterOnSetFocus )
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.autocomplete_and_process_enterOnTextEnter )
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def no_process_enterOnKillFocus( self, event ):
        print('leave no_process_enter\n')
        event.Skip()

    def no_process_enterOnSetFocus( self, event ):
        print('enter no_process_enter')
        event.Skip()

    def no_autocompleteOnKillFocus( self, event ):
        print('leave no_autocomplete\n')
        event.Skip()

    def no_autocompleteOnSetFocus( self, event ):
        print('enter no_autocomplete')
        event.Skip()

    def no_autocompleteOnTextEnter( self, event ):
        print('no_autocomplete - ENTER pressed')
        event.Skip()

    def autocomplete_and_process_enterOnKillFocus( self, event ):
        print('leave autocomplete_and_process_enter\n')
        event.Skip()

    def autocomplete_and_process_enterOnSetFocus( self, event ):
        print('enter autocomplete_and_process_enter')
        event.Skip()

    def autocomplete_and_process_enterOnTextEnter( self, event ):
        print('autocomplete_and_process_enter - ENTER pressed')
        event.Skip()

    def OnKeyDown( self, event ):
        #print(event.GetKeyCode())
        if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_TAB:
            print('navigate to next element')
            event.EventObject.Navigate()
            event.Skip(False)
        else:
            event.Skip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show(True)

    
    frame.no_process_enter.AutoComplete(['Hello', 'World'])
    frame.autocomplete_and_process_enter.AutoComplete(['Foo', 'Bar'])

    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeeded in solving the problem. The trick is to catch the event before it is passed to the event chain and to do the tab traversal manually.

To do so you have to implement the [`TryBefore`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.EvtHandler.html#wx.EvtHandler.TryBefore) method and limits the execution to the text fields that do not work. To enable bidirectional navigation the parameter [`not event.ShiftDown()`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.KeyboardState.html#wx.KeyboardState.ShiftDown) is passed to the [`event.EventObject.Navigate`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html?highlight=navigate#wx.Window.Navigate) method.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( -1,-1 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        Sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.panel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        inputSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.no_process_enter = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        inputSizer.Add( self.no_process_enter, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.no_autocomplete = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
        inputSizer.Add( self.no_autocomplete, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter = wx.TextCtrl( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER )
        inputSizer.Add( self.autocomplete_and_process_enter, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        ButtonSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.ButtonSizerOK = wx.Button( self.panel, wx.ID_OK )
        ButtonSizer.AddButton( self.ButtonSizerOK )
        self.ButtonSizerCancel = wx.Button( self.panel, wx.ID_CANCEL )
        ButtonSizer.AddButton( self.ButtonSizerCancel )
        ButtonSizer.Realize();

        inputSizer.Add( ButtonSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.panel.SetSizer( inputSizer )
        self.panel.Layout()
        inputSizer.Fit( self.panel )
        Sizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( Sizer )
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.no_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.no_process_enterOnKillFocus )
        self.no_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.no_process_enterOnSetFocus )
        
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.no_autocompleteOnKillFocus )
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.no_autocompleteOnSetFocus )
        self.no_autocomplete.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.no_autocompleteOnTextEnter )
        
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.autocomplete_and_process_enterOnKillFocus )
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.autocomplete_and_process_enterOnSetFocus )
        self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.autocomplete_and_process_enterOnTextEnter )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def TryBefore(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, wx.KeyEvent):
            if event.GetEventObject().GetId() in (self.no_autocomplete.GetId(), self.autocomplete_and_process_enter.GetId()):
                if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_TAB:
                    event.EventObject.Navigate(not event.ShiftDown())
                    return False
        return wx.Frame.TryBefore(self, event)

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def no_process_enterOnKillFocus( self, event ):
        print('leave no_process_enter\n')
        event.Skip()

    def no_process_enterOnSetFocus( self, event ):
        print('enter no_process_enter') 
        event.Skip()

    def no_autocompleteOnKillFocus( self, event ):
        print('leave no_autocomplete\n')
        event.Skip()

    def no_autocompleteOnSetFocus( self, event ):
        print('enter no_autocomplete')
        event.Skip()

    def no_autocompleteOnTextEnter( self, event ):
        print('no_autocomplete - ENTER pressed')
        event.Skip()

    def autocomplete_and_process_enterOnKillFocus( self, event ):
        print('leave autocomplete_and_process_enter\n')
        event.Skip()

    def autocomplete_and_process_enterOnSetFocus( self, event ):
        print('enter autocomplete_and_process_enter')
        event.Skip()

    def autocomplete_and_process_enterOnTextEnter( self, event ):
        print('autocomplete_and_process_enter - ENTER pressed')
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show(True)

    
    frame.no_process_enter.AutoComplete(['Hello', 'World'])
    frame.autocomplete_and_process_enter.AutoComplete(['Foo', 'Bar'])

    app.MainLoop()
```